# ASP.NET Core, 3 layer architecture how to send class from service layer to api layer?

Tags: asp.net-core, web, architecture

I am writing an asp.net core application, I have implemented a data access layer, a service layer and I am now working on an API layer, with controllers. What I don´t get is how to give the controllers in the API layer access to the service class I have implemented in the service layer. They only option I can find is `builder.Services.AddScoped` but that doesn't seem applicable.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is a MVC (since you mentioned controller), you need to use dependency injection (DI)

1. Declare your service class (or interface) as singleton in startup
2. Receive instance of your service in constructor of your controller
3. Use methods of your service inside controller as needed

more info
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-6.0